# javaee6 reading dynamic # of post form fields and redirect to a new page

Tags: servlets, paypal, java-ee-6

I'm wondering what's the best approach for posting dynamic # of form fields and then redirect to a new page.

My requirement is like checkout in paypal, from the merchant store you click checkout and it redirects to paypal showing all the items you've checkout and will ask you to login.

This is not possible with jersey because it doesn't open a page and just handles web servlet request. So I'm stuck with servlet? Is servlet doPost (read posted data and store to database) then response.sendRedirect to the login page (requery the data for display) the best approach?

So:

```
merchant store->checkout.click->servlet.doPost(savePostedData) + servlet.sendRedirect(newUrl)->newUrl.queryData().showOnPage?
```

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the functionality mentioned above by using Servlet. For example I have checkout servlet, this is what I've done:

```
public class CheckoutServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -64282312915404473L;
    @Inject
    private Logger log;

@Override   
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    doPost(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Enumeration<String> fields = request.getParameterNames();
    while (fields.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = fields.nextElement();
        log.debug("field {}={}", name, request.getParameter(name));
    }

    response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
}

}
```